# Debugging failed installation to custom library

Tags: r

I'm a bit at a loss as to why installation of a package is failing. I'm installing in Docker with the following:

```
Sys.getenv('CRAN_MIRROR')
# [1] "https://cloud.r-project.org"
.libPaths()
# [1] "/home/jovyan/r_lib"            "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library"
# [3] "/usr/lib/R/site-library"       "/usr/lib/R/library"   
install.packages('classInt', repos = Sys.getenv('CRAN_MIRROR'))
```

Failure at:

> Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
>     there is no package called ‘e1071’

However, in fact `e1071` is most definitely installed & available:

```
list.files(.libPaths()[1L], pattern = 'e1071')
# [1] "e1071"
library(e1071) # works
install.packages('e1071', repos = Sys.getenv('CRAN_MIRROR')) # also works
```

I don't understand why installation is failing... is there something I'm missing?

The only other thing I can think of is a permissions mismatch between `library` and `install.packages` internally? But also

```
system('whoami')
# root
```

Further, it's definitely a problem of the custom library, because:

```
.libPaths(.libPaths()[-1L]) # remove custom lib
install.packages('classInt', repos = Sys.getenv('CRAN_MIRROR')) # successful
```

Comment: Might be version problem?

Comment: When I upgraded to 3.6 I got plenty of similar errors. Often I solved the problem removing the offending dependencies and reinstalling them back again. They wouk `library` successfully, and would definitely be there, but wouldn't allow me to install a dependent package.

Comment: @PavoDive the thing is this is a Docker build. So literally the command before is installing R... surprising for such a clean build to run into the issue